# Who has done research on marital status? I am running a logistic regression analysis

Tags: r, logistic, interpretation, regression-coefficients, odds

I have NLSY97 data and specifically look at a cross-section (2013 data), where respondents are between 28-32 and who got married and who didn't. I want to see which of the independent variables are significant in predicting marital status and which one predicts the highest log odds. This is the model I run in R:

```
glm(formula = married ~ Female + age + Black + Hispanic + Msa + 
    rel_pref + yinc + hrs_wrkd + degree + degree_fem, family = binomial(link = logit), 
    data = nlsy2)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.4025  -1.0825   0.4939   1.0455   2.1968  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -5.585e+00  5.717e-01  -9.768  < 2e-16 ***
Female       4.595e-01  9.803e-02   4.687 2.77e-06 ***
age          1.691e-01  1.830e-02   9.241  < 2e-16 ***
Black       -1.278e+00  6.716e-02 -19.029  < 2e-16 ***
Hispanic    -2.943e-01  6.510e-02  -4.520 6.18e-06 ***
Msa         -5.146e-01  5.171e-02  -9.952  < 2e-16 ***
rel_pref     5.254e-01  5.556e-02   9.457  < 2e-16 ***
yinc         1.007e-05  1.176e-06   8.562  < 2e-16 ***
hrs_wrkd     2.689e-05  2.577e-05   1.044   0.2967    
degree       1.026e-01  4.353e-02   2.356   0.0185 *  
degree_fem  -3.317e-02  5.766e-02  -0.575   0.5651    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 9851.6  on 7106  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 8945.5  on 7096  degrees of freedom
AIC: 8967.5

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

> exp(coef(married1))
(Intercept)      Female         age       Black    Hispanic         Msa    rel_pref        yinc 
0.003755289 1.583298625 1.184297429 0.278581731 0.745073838 0.597713776 1.691114349 1.000010068 
   hrs_wrkd      degree  degree_fem 
1.000026891 1.108001765 0.967370363
```

Some of the odds make sense, I am a little confused with the coefficients for Black and Hispanics and want to make sure I am interpreting these right: If I look at the coefficient for Black, does that mean that odds for a Black person to get married are higher by 0.27 times as compared to Whites, which is the base group?

Comment: 0.28, not 0.27. Anyway, not exactly: that's the relative odds increase of a Black person vs  White one, *everything else being the same*. Remember always to specify that the other predictors are fixed (or being controlled for).  BTW, not a huge reduction in deviance wrt the null model: maybe there could be a better model.

Comment: What if the relative odds for a Black person would be lower than for a White person? I am confused which values odds would take on, as odds can only range from 0 to plus infinity. When simply looking at correlation between Black and marital status, these two are negatively correlated. But the glm outcome provides that Blacks are more likely to get married than Whites, holding everything else fixed. Can someone make sense out of it, or provide an explanation? The deviance doesn't looks well, I will try out some other variable combinations for this model.

Comment: No, not higher, the coefficient is **negative**. The odds ratio is $exp^{-1.278}$, which is 0.28 times of the odds or white. If the odds of white being married is 1, then the odds of black being married is 1 X 0.28, which is 0.28. Black is in no way "higher".

Comment: Ok, great! Life makes sense again :)

Comment: @krilee wait, don't go "fishing for significance", that's not what I suggested. If you keep trying interactions among variables and/or selecting variables with higher $p-$values, you will always find a model which reduces deviance, and which is also meaningless (in particular, $p-$values won't have the usual interpretation as probability of getting the same statistic or a more extreme one under the conditional null). I was suggesting of thinking if, based on domain knowledge, previous research, etc. you could be able to think of a better model.

Comment: I understand that this is a big issue. The problem I am encountering is that there is not much research done on what determines marital status, and I feel lost in how to evaluate my results, especially because the log odd are very close to zero, but nonetheless, significant. I will present my results tomorrow,and instead of trying to come up with different specifications or new variables,I am rather thinking of how to explain the flaws of this model(why the coefficients are small but significant)and how it can be improved.This might be not a good model, but a discussion might still add value

Comment: I understand that this is a big issue. The problem I am encountering is that there is not much research done on what determines marital status, and I feel lost in how to evaluate my results, especially because the log odd are very close to zero, but nonetheless,significant. I will present my results tomorrow,and instead of trying to come up with different specifications or new variables,I am rather thinking of how to explain the flaws of this model(why the coefficients are small but significant)and how it can be improved.This might be not a good model, but a discussion might still add value

Comment: Please, respond if you have found any researches on this topic. Will be very greatful for help!